# MySQL Using Subquery To Get Table Name?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select some data from a MySQL database.

I have a table containing business details, and a seperate one containing a list of trades. As we have multiple trades

**business_details**

```
id | business_name | trade_id | package_id
1  | Happy News    |    12    |    1
```

This is the main table, contains the business name, the trade ID and the package ID

**shop_trades**

```
id | trade
1  | newsagents
```

This contains the trade type of the business

**configuration_packages**

```
id | name_of_trade_table
1  | shop_trades
2  | leisure_trades
```

This contains the name of the trade table to look in

So, basically, if I want to find the trade type (e.g., newsagent, fast food, etc) I look in the XXXX_trades table. But I first need to look up the name of XXXX from the configuration_packages table.

What I would normally do is 2 SQL queries:

```
SELECT business_details.*, configuration_packages.name_of_trade_table
FROM business_details, configuration_packages
WHERE business_details.package_id = configuration_packages.id
AND business_details.id = '1'
```

That gives me the name of the database table to look in for the trade name, so I look up the name of the table

```
SELECT trade FROM XXXX WHERE id='YYYY'
```

Where `XXXX` is the name of the table returned as part of the first query and `YYYY` is the id of the package, again returned from the first query.

Is there a way to combine these two queries so that I only run one?

I've used subqueries before, but only on the SELECT side of the query - not the FROM side.

Comment: Why have you got 2 separate tables `shop_trades` and `leisure_trades`? Rather than one `trades`?

Comment: Thanks. Valid question, but the two 'packages' store different rates. They aren't identical.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. I think the only two options for you are to carry on as you are or try and make some more generic database structure applicable to both trades.

Comment: It doesn't matter. in a relational database, relations being built based on the field value, not table name. So, make your database relational first and then solve rate issue. Not a big deal. Another table with rates.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel, @Martin Smith: Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way. I'll give the database schema some more thought.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, this is handled by a union in a single query.

Normalization gets you to a logical model.  This helps better understand the data.  It is common to denormalize when implementing the model.   Subtypes as you have here are commonly implemented in two ways:

- Seperate tables as you have, which makes retrieval difficult.  This results in your question about how to retreive the data.
- A common table for all subtypes with a subtype indicator.  This may result in columns which are always null for certain subtypes.  It simplifies data access, and may alter the way that the subtypes are handled in code.

If the extra columns for a subtype are relatively rarely accessed, then you may use a hybrid implementation where the common columns are in the type table, and some or all of the subtype columns are in a subtype table.  This is more complex to code.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, and it sounds like a problem with your model.

Why don't you put `shop_trades` and `leisure_traces` into the same table with one column to distinct between the two?

Comment: Thanks but it's insurance related and, for example, shops will have more rates per trade than a leisure...

Comment: For example, a shop would have a 'target stock' rate, whereby a guest house wouldn't

Comment: True normalisation states you should avoid storing empty values which is why i've approached it from this angle

Comment: @Sjwdavies - You could possibly have an inheritance type of arrangement where you have a common table that stores the attributes common to all trades and then further tables to store the specific additional attributes. It appears in the example query you have given the column list doesn't change dependant on trade type.

Comment: @MartinSmith - You're right, in the example here there is no difference in the columns. I wrote this up in as simple a way as I could because I didn't want to confuse people. The two trades do have different fields though.

Comment: true normalization is pure theory and in practice it always hurts

Answer (score 0):

If this is possible, try this

```
SELECT trade
FROM (SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' FROM 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'.'TABLES' 
      WHERE 'TABLE_SCHEMA'='*schema name*')
WHERE id='YYYY'
```

UPDATE:

I think the code I have above is not possible. :|

Comment: Note that you can always delete your answer if you realize that it is incorrect.